# Noob question : why are my Cycles render too bright, even with no lights?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Why are my Cycles render so bright, I even tried to erase all lights and it makes no difference... :(

Below render example. It's supposed to be a commercial kitchen. Looks great with Eevee but with Cycles looks like big snow storm...

[image: render]

Comment: Do you use materials as light emitters? Otherwise - hard to tell, since we don't see anything but your result.

Comment: Yes there are material light emitters where the lights on the ceiling are. I guess they have to purpose since the real area lights are almost at the same position?

Comment: Well you seem to be right, it seems to the be the emission material that causes all this... I will try to remove them all and see what happens.

Comment: Ok nevermind, I found it. My emission material was too strong in Cycle, especially combined with the lights. I removed the lights and kept the emission material but lowered the strenght. Thx mate!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have inadvertently enabled the Ambient Occlusion setting in the World properties. Disable Ambient Occlusion again and all should be fine.

[image]

Comment: Ambient Occlusion is already off. :(

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing in V2.93.4 and I used the file before many times. Now I have the same thing even after getting rid of all lights and hdri.